# How do I set my password for a new Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure

Using Sql Databases inside the Azure Portal, I am able to create a new database. 
I am not asked for a a password when creating the database.
However when I try to manage the database I am asked for a password.

My Microsoft live login does not work.

Thus I am in a situation where I can delete the database but not use it.

How do I set the password?

Comment: here's the full Azure SQL Login help : https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because the password gets up when I create the SERVER. The login is asking for the server password and the database is optional.

Comment: So how do you find out what the server password is or change it?